# How can I change the 'active' monitor on gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, multi-monitor

I'm using debian 8.2 with gnome3 (gnome shell) with 2 monitors.

Primary/Secondary screen is configured correctly.

- When I start up my system and open up an application **using ALT+F2 or by using a shortcut** it always opens on the secondary monitor. I would expect it to open on the primary monitor (even the prompt window for ALT+F2 opens on the secondary monitor!).
- But when I open any application **using the application menu** (which appears on the primary monitor always), it opens on the primary monitor as expected. Same if I start up my system and click on the primary monitor before pressing ALT+F2 or a shortcut.

It seems like there is always one 'active' monitor, on which new windows open. This seems to be the secondary monitor on system startup. How can I change this?